# Create a database with an arrival time and access to it in the process flow

Tags: anylogic

I would like to create a database with different arrival times that my forklifts pick the pallets  (rack pick) to the certain times. How could I do this? Which process blocks could I use to access to a database with arrival times? 
For example at 10am on May 20 45 pallets should pick out of the pallet rack. I tested it with a delay block and it works but only with different hours where the pallets get picked and not an specific date. The important thing is the date which I get from a database.
[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXngt.png)

Comment: Hi @JackSock, while this is surely possible, it sounds like a very bad idea from a modelling perspective. Why would you want to dictate when forklifts pick up stuff? Sounds like you got some data from the past and want to duplicate this. But typically, you should NOT do it like that. Just my 50 cents to re-think if this is really needed this way :)

Comment: I need it because I want to replace the loading truck which also would load the pallets to a certain time. Please could you tell me how I could do this? Its very important for my project

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to have your in-rack agents (after your RackStore block) sit in a Wait block, and be freed from there (using the Wait block's `free` function) --- to then carry on to a RackPick block --- via AnyLogic dynamic events whose timings come from a database table.

(Your model as-is will just have your agents immediately exiting the rack and going to the Sink because the Queue does not stop them leaving.)

Your model startup would loop through the rows in the table and create dynamic event instances with the appropriate timeouts (delays from model start), and with a dynamic event parameter which specified the number of pallets to pick (and thus the number to free from the Wait block).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rossiter. I have another question: How can I get the access from the dynamic event to the database

Comment: *to the timeouts which I get from a dbase

Comment: You do it the other way round as stated: read the data from the database (which could be durations in model time units, dates, etc.) and use the times therein to schedule the dynamic event instances. See the help for use of dynamic events and the database query wizard.

Comment: thank you for yor help @Stuar Rossiter. I understand what you mean but the problem is still that I don't know how to connect the dynamic event with the database. So I have a dbase with different dates but how to access on it? With a parameter? or how can I get the dates into my dynamic event